# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'recv' while running the sub_file.py

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

when I run the sub_file.py program there is an error like this :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'recv'
```

this is the sub_file.py code:

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
import base64

broker_address="mqtt.eclipseprojects.io"

port = 1883
client = mqtt.Client("P2") #create new instance

client.connect(broker_address,port) #connect to broker

def on_message(cln, obj, msg):
  print("new message")
  data = msg.payload.decode()
  msg = str(data)
  img = msg.encode('ascii')
  with open('iris.jpg', 'wb') as fd:
    final_data = base64.b64decode(img)
    fd.write(final_data)
    fd.close()

def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
  print("subscribe success")

client.subscribe("photo_topic_file")


client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
print("Subscribing...")
client.loop_start()

client.on_message = on_message

client.loop_forever()
```

and this the pub_file.py code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import base64
import time

broker_address="mqtt.eclipseprojects.io"

port = 1883
client = mqtt.Client("P1")


f = open("data.jpg", "rb")
isi_file = f.read()
convert_result_ke_base64 = base64.b64encode(isi_file)


client.connect(broker_address, port)
client.loop_start()
result = client.publish("photo_topic_file", convert_result_ke_base64)

if result[0] == 0:
    print("publish success")
else:
    print("publish failed")
    
time.sleep(5)
client.loop_stop()
```

when i run the pub_file.py the program worked properly but when i run the sub_file.py it show the error

can someone fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to S/O! Can you provide the **full** error output (all the lines starting from `Traceback (most recent call last):`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
print("Subscribing...")
client.loop_start()

client.on_message = on_message

client.loop_forever()
```

You are starting two message loops:

- One with `client.loop_start()`
- The other with `client.loop_forever()`

This causes issues because the code is written with an assumption that only one message loop will be running.

The simplest way to resolve this is to remove the `client.loop_start()`.

Note that it's probably better to call `subscribe` from `on_connect` as shown in ["Getting Started"](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#getting-started). I would also suggest setting the callbacks before you call `connect` (setting `on_message` after starting the loop could, potentially, lead to message loss).